# Nuclear operators

Tags: functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

While studying for my thesis (in dynamical systems) I've encountered multiple times with the concept of nuclear operators and nuclear spaces, often linked with the works of Grothendieck. For example, when studying the generalized transfer operator (or Ruelle operator) for the Gauss Map, Dieter Mayer points out that this operator is in fact nuclear (On the thermodynamic formalism for the Gauss map). While I can understand the definition of a nuclear operator, I still cannot get the real importance of being nuclear of order zero. Usually I'm interested in spectral gap properties for transfer operators, but is there any implication of the nuclear property?
Also, any reference for nuclear operators and Fredholm kernels would be appreciated, since trying to learn directly from Grothendieck's works has been really difficult for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably you meant to write "cannot get" ... the importance of order 0... Anyway, some introductory notes about this are at http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/06d_nuclear_spaces_I.pdf

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo!

Comment: Dear @paulgarrett , I have read your introductory notes on nuclear frechet spaces, and they helped me to understand why should we introduce a class of spaces where there is a categorically genuine tensor product (the exposition was really clear!). How can we get a general definition for nuclear spaces?

Comment: There are at least two approaches to a "general" definition: Gelfand et al have noted that in many cases where a space is a (proj) lim of Banach spaces with "trace class" transition maps, the limitands are _cofinal_ with Hilbert spaces also with trace-class transition maps, due to various forms of Sobolev imbedding theorems. Thus,  in practice, we reduce to the Hilbert-space case. There is also a general argument that constructs a Hilbert space structure on otherwise-Banach limitands... Third, in principle, treat Banach? I do not know how to do the latter. The first scenario is best, I think.

Comment: I don't know if you are still interested in this problem. I'm actually working on a similar topic. In my understanding, since the transfer operator $L$ is a nuclear operator, you can calculate the trace $\operatorname{tr}(L)$. And this helps when you want to compute the dynamical zeta function which is actually $\operatorname{det}(I-zL)$. Being of order zero implies the convergence rate of the expansion.

Answer (score -1):

Being muclear for an operaror helps to calculate its trace and determinant of the form I+ operator. In banach spaces similar results are given but we need aproximation property.